# What is google's policy regarding the images of the apps?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to use the Images of the apps that are shared by the developers for displaying on the Google Play Store (The app/game screenshots).

Am I allowed to use them? Can they be reproduced?

Comment: Why? Are you trying to make a clone of play store and rip their images without **their consent**? You're asking for legal trouble if that's the case!

Comment: No no its not like that :)

I am a blogger and writing a post about some Android apps so thats why wanted to know If I can use those images or not.

Comment: Best advice - check with the original developer/team of those products you're referring to, the one thing my interpretation in my answer below, is *streams* that can be referred to what you see on the landing page, to use them without Google's consent would IMHO be a violation also, its the wording "stream" which can apply there as well..

Comment: I have tried searching the banner images on Google Play and these images are used in alot of website. So you think all of them are violating ?

Comment: No!! :) I meant you taking from the actual play store site, I would guess, not them, the developer/team uploaded screenshots, along with their apk's, Google uses those in the banners... its wise counsel to ask for permission first anyway...

Comment: @t0mm13b, I think one could assume when Google states *"Capturing of Streams. You may not use Google Play or any Product in conjunction with any stream-ripping, stream capture or similar software to record or create a copy of any Product that is presented to you in streaming format."* it means **don't rip Google Play Movies**, as it is the only product presented in streaming format, AFAIK.

Comment: PS: That's the *logical* assumption, however maybe not a *safe* assumptions, laws and logic not always go together.

Comment: @ruda.almeida possibly yes, and that's true, it can be open to interpretation, i.e. not a safe assumption, because the landing page from desktop PC, shows what resembles a stream of images.... understand... its vague hence why I opined about it :)

Comment: I should seek permission of whom Google Play or the Developer who uploaded the screens. Plus it would become quite a tedious task for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the terms and conditions of the site, specifically, under sub-heading **6. Rights and Restrictions**, and I'll quote:

> ***No Public Performance.*** You agree not to display content contained in
>   Products in whole or in part as part of any public performance or
>   display even if no fee is charged (except where such use would not
>   constitute a copyright infringement). Use of a tool or feature
>   provided as an authorized part of Google Play (for example, “Social
>   Recommendations”, as defined in the Music terms below) is permitted,
>   provided that as you use the tool or feature as specifically permitted
>   and only in the exact manner specified and enabled by Google.
>
> Capturing of Streams. You may not use Google Play or any Product in
>   conjunction with any stream-ripping, stream capture or similar
>   software to record or create a copy of any Product that is presented
>   to you in streaming format.
>
> Sharing. You may not use Products as part of any service for sharing,
>   lending or multi-person use, or for the purpose of any other
>   institution, except as specifically permitted and only in the exact
>   manner specified and enabled by Google (for example, through “Social
>   Recommendations”).
>
> ***Proprietary Notices.*** You may not remove any watermarks, labels or
>   other legal or proprietary notices included in any Product, and you
>   may not attempt to modify any Products obtained through Google Play,
>   including any modification for the purpose of disguising or changing
>   any indications of the ownership or source of a Product.

The italic-ized and bolded heading is my emphasis and thus would lead to OP's intention to be in violation!